# Submit Laravel form after Authentication

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a modal form with tabs. I use AJAX to submit the form, which works fine. I want the form should be public: if the user is not logged in it should display the login, and submit the form after logging in using AJAX and Laravel.

```
public function acServices()
{
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$post = new Ac_services_request  ;
$post->user_id = $id;
$post->services = Request::input('service');
$post->ac_type = Request::input('ac_type');
$post->type_services = Request::input('ac_services');
$post->no_of_ac = Request::input('no_of_ac');
$post->other_info = Request::input('other_info');
$post->address = Request::input('addr');
$post->landmark = Request::input('landmark');
$post->lga = Request::input('lga');
$post->specific_location = Request::input('specific_location');
$post->date = Request::input('date');
$post->time = Request::input('time');
$post->mobile = Request::input('');
$post->code = $string."".$id;

$post->save();
return 'success';
}



<div class="modal fade ac-services ativa-scroll" data-backdrop="static"  
  data-keyboard="false" id="ac-services" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog "  role="document">
        <div class="modal-content " >
         <button  type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
     label="Close">
      <span style="color: white;" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

  <form class="contact" >
  <div class="setup-content" id="step-1">

  <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
      <p>Select AC type</p>
   <select required="required" class="form-control lg" name="ac_type">

          <option></option>
           <option>Window AC(S)</option>
           <option>Split AC(S)</option>
            <option>Window AC(S) and Split AC(S)</option>
           </select>
     </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="service" value="A/C Repairs and Services">
      <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
       <p>Select type of service you need</p>
     <select required="required" class="form-control lg" name="ac_services">
        <option></option>
           <option>Installation of new AC</option>
           <option>General Cleaning</option>
           <option>Un-installation of existing AC</option>
           <option>Repairs (Diagnosis and rectification of AC(s)</option>
           </select>

         </div>   
        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" 
        type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">

        <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
             <p>How many AC(s)</p>

      <input  type="number" required="required" class="form-control lg" 
      name="no_of_ac" placeholder="Enter Number of AC e.g 2" >
                 </div>
     <div class="form-group ">
           <p>Other Informations</p>
      <textarea required="required" rows="5" cols="65" name="other_info">
      </textarea>
      </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" 
      type="button">Back</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" 
      type="button">Next</button>

      </div>
      <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">

      <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
      <p>Where do you need the services ?</p>

      <span>House/Flat No, Street, City</span>
      <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control lg" 
     name="addr">
     </div>

      <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
       <span>Landmark</span>
       <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control lg" 
        name="landmark">
         </div>

          <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
       <span>LGA</span>
       <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control lg" 
    name="lga" >
    </div>
     <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
     <span>Any other specific location direction/description?</span>
     <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control lg" 
       name="specific_location"><br>
      <span><b> Note: Accurate location helps us reach you promptly </b> 
    </span>
    </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">

   <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" 
    type="button">Back</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" 
   type="button">Next</button>
   </div>

   <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4">

     <div class="form-group input-group col-md-9">
   <p>Pick Date</p>
   <input type="date" required="required" class="form-control lg" 
   name="date">                  </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
   <p>Select Service Time</p>
                  <select required="required" class="form-control lg" name="time">
                  <option></option>
                    <option>10:00am - 11:00am</option>
                    <option>11:00am - 12:00pm</option>
                       <option>12:00pm - 1:00pm</option>
                        <option>1:00pm - 2:00pm</option>
                         <option>2:00pm -3:00pm</option>
                          <option>3:00pm - 4:00pm</option>
                           <option>4:00pm - 5:00pm</option>
                  </select> 
</div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-right" id="submit" data-target=".success">submit</button>
</div>
```

```
  <script>
   $('#ac-services').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   location.reload();
   })
   $(function() {
   $("button#submit").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
   url: 'ac-booked-service',
   type: "post",
   data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
   beforeSend: function() {                    
   $empty = $('form.contact').find("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
    });
   if($empty.length) {
   alert('Please fill all the field');
   return false;
   }else{
   return true;
   };
   },

  success: function (result) {
   window.location.replace('/user/dashboard');  

        },
        error: function(){
    alert("failure");
    }  
 });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake I've included my code, im newbie.

Comment: Could you try to explain a little more exactly what you need help with here? I see you've posted code and information about what you need it to do, which is great, but it's still not clear exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: @Cody i dont know how to hold the inputed datas on session and submit after authentication

Comment: Generally your authentication method logs the user in and returns a cookie which authorizes them to use the application. At that point, the cookie can be used to contact the API which could return the current logged in user's information.

Answer (score 0):

It might be beneficial for you to follow a few tutorials to gain some understanding around this concept.

- [Simple and Easy Laravel Login Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication)
- [Laravel Docs on Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)
- [Auth0 Tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/)